# MPI in parallel programming

Tags: parallel-processing

I have a project but I didn't solve it.

Computing the sum of the elements of an array
The objective of the problem is to write a serial, then a parallel program that takes as input an array of integers, stored in an ASCII file with one integer per line, and prints out the sum of the elements in the file. For instance:
% cat input
1
24
9
% my_program input
34

Write a serial program to solve this problem. Name the source code sum-serial.c then write an MPI implementation of the above program in which a master process reads in the entire input file and then dispatches pieces of it to workers, which these pieces being of as equal size as possible. The master must also perform computation. Each processor computes a local sum and results are then collected and aggregated by the master. This implementation should not use any collective communications, but only point-to-point.

Comment: You can't just copy and paste a homework problem into SO. You have to tell us what you've tried. What didn't work? What are you specifically asking. We're not going to do it all for you.

Comment: The author directly copied a homework problem without demonstrating effort on his/her end.